# New Task is not being picked up by a thread once it is done with the first one and goes in wait state for forever

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

Sample code:

```
public class ThreadTest{

    public static void main(String ...arg){
           try{
                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
                for(int i=0; i < noOfTask; i++){
                    executor.execute(new ImplRunnable(connectionPool.getConnection()));
                }
                executor.shutdown();
                //Wait for all threads completion
               executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
            }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
            //close database connections etc.
            }
        }
    }
    class ImplRunnable implements Runnable{
             private Connection conn;
              public ImplRunnable(Connection conn){
                     this.conn = conn;
              }

            public void run(){
                try{
                    for(int i =0; i < 1000000; i++){
                        counts++;
                    }

                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    //close all open statements
                    try{
                        conn.close();
                    }catch(Exception exp){
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
           }
        }
```

My system has 4 cores therefore the pool size is 4 and I have 10 tasks to do

The for loop is opening 10 threads but 4 threads are running at a time. But the problem is when a thread is completed processing it is going in waiting state for forever and not picking up next task for processing. What is wrong with the above code?

Please suggest...

Comment: Does replacing `while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}` with `executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` help? Also your code does not compile (missing `Runnable` implementation). Finally the loop is not opening 10 threads, it submits 10 tasks to the pool, having 4 threads (so 6 will queue up). Besides your code is fine.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz thx for your response. I do have impl class for Runnable.. This is just sample code... I will try whatever you have mentioned above.

Comment: hey @TomaszNurkiewicz it looks like executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS) is faster than while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}.. why is it? any thoughts?

Comment: Of course it's faster, it simply waits on a lock instead of busy waiting, actively looping and burning 100% of one core.

Comment: I made that change but still same problem.. I can see Entry and Exit statements on console for all threads, but when all threads are done with first round of processing then they are going in wait state for forever and not being picked-up by ThreadPoolExecutor for next tasks... Any clue guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault only when I was assigning a connection to the thread from Connection Pool then I was not closing it when thread is done with processing. When I closed connection at end of a thread then it started working and threads are properly being assigned for next tasks.